# Video won't start for some m3u8 playlist

Tags: ios, video, react-native

I am trying to play video in my react-native app on iOS but have run into a problem with m3u8 playlists.
For `example.link.myplace/play_1` I get the following m3u8-playlist as response

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=3000000
0.m3u8
```

and the video starts immediately and plays just fine but for `example.link.myplace/play_2` I get the following m3u8-playlist

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=986000,RESOLUTION=768x432,CODECS="avc1.77.30, mp4a.40.2"
index_0_av.m3u8?e=82d461566017da20&
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=238000,RESOLUTION=512x288,CODECS="avc1.66.30, mp4a.40.2"
index_1_av.m3u8?e=82d461566017da20&
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=346000,RESOLUTION=512x288,CODECS="avc1.66.30, mp4a.40.2"
index_2_av.m3u8?e=82d461566017da20&
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=454000,RESOLUTION=512x288,CODECS="avc1.66.30, mp4a.40.2"
index_3_av.m3u8?e=82d461566017da20&
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=634000,RESOLUTION=512x288,CODECS="avc1.66.30, mp4a.40.2"
index_4_av.m3u8?e=82d461566017da20&
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1678000,RESOLUTION=1280x720,CODECS="avc1.77.30, mp4a.40.2"
index_5_av.m3u8?e=82d461566017da20&
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=2795000,RESOLUTION=1280x720,CODECS="avc1.64001f, mp4a.40.2"
index_6_av.m3u8?e=82d461566017da20&
```

and the video just never starts, I am not even sure it loads.
I would be grateful for any pointers to what I could do to alleviate this.

Snippet from my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "node-forge": "^0.7.1",
    "ramda": "^0.24.1",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
    "react-native": "~0.44.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-side-menu": "^0.20.1",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-native-video": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-video-player": "^0.7.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11"
  }
```

Comment: Adding AllowArbitraryLoads=Yes to AppTransportSecuritySettings solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Adding AllowArbitraryLoads=Yes to AppTransportSecuritySettings solved the problem. – user6343909 just now   edit